# Div width wrong

Tags: html, css

I was inspecting my asp.net page in firefox and discovered that the main page container was 1116.9px instead of the 1024 that its supposed to be.

I couldn't figure out what was the cause so I made this test file:

```
<html>
    <body> 
        <div style="width:100%;max-width:1024px;margin:0 auto;height:1000px;background-color:blue"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and inspected it aswell. This one is even worse - 1428px wide. This only happens in firefox. Am I missing something really fundamental here? Whats going on?

Comment: this must be silly question but are you zooming the page? your test file gave me 1024px.

Comment: I cant reproduce the error as well

Comment: @Syahrul OMG lol. I was too busy pulling my hair out to even consider that. Thanks.

Comment: Working as expected here.

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on the size of your window and device screen. For example, if you have a large monitor and maximize the window to fit the screen, it will enlarge the width. I have a dual monitor setup and I just dragged the window size from the corner to stretch over both screens. I then clicked the Resize tab form the Web Developer Toolbar and it showed : 2442px x 1009px ... However, you can click the Resize to 1024x768 (which is what the page is set to display at normally) and it will resize the window to fit it.

Answer (score -1):

try this...
height:100%;max-height:1000px;